# Laravel 4: DB:select returns rows ordered randomly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

Here is a good one. I am running the following query via DB::select($sql):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `listings`.`listing_id` FROM `listings`
STRAIGHT_JOIN `listings_coords` ON `listings_coords`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id`

LEFT JOIN `listings_lettings`
ON `listings`.`transaction_type` != 1 AND `listings_lettings`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id`
LEFT JOIN `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies`
ON `listings`.`transaction_type` != 1 AND `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies`.`listings_lettings_rent_frequency_id` = `listings_lettings`.`listings_lettings_rent_frequency_id`
LEFT JOIN `listings_units` ON `listings`.`listings_unit_id` = `listings_units`.`listings_unit_id`

WHERE
`listings`.`active` = 1
AND `listings`.`published_flag` = 1

AND `listings`.`country_id` = 223

AND `listings`.`property_type` = 1
AND `listings`.`listings_status_id` = 1

AND `listings`.`lat` BETWEEN 51.391407971014 AND 51.623292028986
AND `listings`.`lng` BETWEEN -0.31403791919581 AND 0.05851791919581AND st_intersects((SELECT `polygon` FROM locations WHERE location_id = 65), `listings_coords`.`coords`)

ORDER BY

IF(`price_sales` IS NULL AND `price_lettings` IS NULL AND ((`price_per_unit_sales` IS NULL AND `price_per_unit_lettings` IS NULL) OR `max_size` IS NULL), 1,
IFNULL(`price_sales`, IF(`price_lettings` IS NOT NULL, `price_lettings` * IFNULL(`listings_lettings_rent_frequencies`.`months`, 1), IFNULL(`price_per_unit_sales` * `max_size` * `listings_units`.`meters`, `price_per_unit_lettings` * `max_size` * `listings_units`.`meters` * `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies`.`months`)))) DESC

LIMIT 0, 10
```

Now - the query always returns the exact same results when executed on workbench, however the array of objects being returned by the said function is acting weird, that is - it randomises my results:

```
array(10) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#548 (1) {
["listing_id"]=>
string(5) "31299"
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#547 (1) {
["listing_id"]=>
string(5) "19601"
}
[2]=>
object(stdClass)#550 (1) {
["listing_id"]=>
string(4) "6769"
}
[3]=>
object(stdClass)#551 (1) {
["listing_id"]=>
string(5) "19042"
}
[4]=>
object(stdClass)#552 (1) {
["listing_id"]=>
string(5) "24822"
}
[5]=>
object(stdClass)#553 (1) {
["listing_id"]=>
string(4) "6072"
}
[6]=>
object(stdClass)#554 (1) {
["listing_id"]=>
string(5) "19075"
}
[7]=>
object(stdClass)#555 (1) {
["listing_id"]=>
string(5) "34067"
}
[8]=>
object(stdClass)#556 (1) {
["listing_id"]=>
string(4) "6040"
}
[9]=>
object(stdClass)#557 (1) {
["listing_id"]=>
string(4) "6781"
}
}
```

And this is how I dump the query and the results:

```
$result = DB::select($sql);
print_r($sql);
echo "\n\n";
dd($result);
```

With every page refresh the order of the above results changes (although first few remain the same). I've been stuck with it for quite a while now so any hints will be most appreciated!

EDIT:

I got to the point when the following order:

```
IF(`price_sales` IS NULL, 1, 1) DESC
```

is mixing the results and so they appear to be rearranging themselves every now and then. This doesn't make much sense knowing that no matter what the price_sales value is it should always return 1, correct?

EDIT2:

When I moved the ORDER BY to SELECT it showed that values in fact remain the same but the properties are moving around in within groups of the same values. So for example three properties with the sort value of 250 000 are changing their order between each other but not across all the results.

Comment: Something in your database is changing. We have no access to your data, so no one can run the query. You can be 100% certain that PHP isn't randomly reordering your data and that MySQL isn't doing it either. Your order by condition is super ugly and difficult to translate to human. Simplify your order by (say, order by ID), check if the randomness still happens. If not, you can be 100% sure that your data is getting updated, hence the different ordering of results.

Comment: See that's what I thought, although it doesn't seem like there are any random factors in the ORDER BY clause. But i run the query about a hundred times separately and not once has it returned queries in a different order. But yeah indeed when it's listed by listing_id the weird behaviour doesn't occur. Still - why would my query run normally when executed on workbench whilst acting weird in here?

Comment: Well, I don't have access to your database but my suspect would be the data being changed somehow. There is no reason why order by would yield different results using the same dataset. If you find the gremlin troubling you, do post the solution, I'm interested to see what really happened.

Comment: I suspect your ORDER BY always sorts on 1. I would recommend moving it entirely to an extra field in the SELECT, and then ordering by that. Makes it more visible what's actually happening there and why.

Comment: Indeed I started to notice the same behaviour when executing the query in workbench. It's definitely a MySQL issue, I moved the sorting to select as requested. The returned values remain the same however the listings are moving around in within certain values. So for the same values the listings are randomised. What could possibly provoke such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the problem is MySQL does NOT assume any specific order if none is provided. That means - with every query run listings might be sorted in a different way. My problem was - for listings with the same sorting value the order was random within the ones with the same value. Since technically 90% of the time the values were in fact different the problem was not as easy to spot.